# How to compare 2 worksheets by ID with vba

Tags: vba

I have been trying to create a vba code for my project. I need to check if 1 cell in specific row by ID has bigger or smaller value than 1 cell with same ID in other worksheet in own!

I have following code which is working until setting the d value to 8:

```
    Sub Compare_ID_ProductCode()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, a As Range, b As Range, d As Integer
    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each c In w1.Range("C2", w1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set a = w2.Columns(1).Find(c.Value, lookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            If w1.Cells(c.row, 3).Value = w2.Cells(a.row, 1).Value Then
                d = 8
                For Each a In w2.Range("Columns(6)", w2.Range("a.Rows" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
                    Set b = w1.Rows(c).Find(e.Value, lookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not b Is Nothing Then
                        If w1.Cells(c.row, Columns(d)).Value > w2.Cells(b.row, Columns(d)).Value Then
                            w1.Cells(c.row, Columns(d)).Cell.Color = vbGreen
                        End If

                        If w1.Cells(c.row, Columns(d)).Value < w2.Cells(b.row, Columns(d)).Value Then
                            w1.Cells(c.row, Columns(d)).Cell.Color = vbRed
                        End If

                    End If
                    d = d + 1
                Next a
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    End Sub
```

When I run it, it shows (Method 'Range' of object "_Worksheet" failed) error?
What I should do?

Thank you every tips are helpful!

-Reijo

Comment: Add Option Explicit at the top, on what line does the error occur

Comment: `w2.Range("Columns(6)", w2.Range("a.Rows" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp))` wont work whatever the value of `d` :/

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you help me, what should I change?